# Rails caching in view -- Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

I have a page where I am iterating through a set of trips with multiple owners and displaying the owner images on the page. I want to cache the entire set of owners in the view, not just the individual partials.

```
<%
  Rails.cache.fetch("trip_owners_#{trip.id.to_s}", expires_in: 7.days) do
    trip.owners.limit(3).each do |owner|
%>
  <%=render_user_card(owner)%>
<% 
     end
   end
%>
```

`render_user_card` basically renders a partial of the individual owner.

```
def render_user_card(user, options = {})
  return "" unless user
  render :partial => 'users/user_card'
end
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error:

```
You are trying to cache a Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached.
```

From my understanding, I have to cache a string. However, I am not sure how to do this. How do I store the composed partials for all my users in a trip and still be able to render the partial? If I store it as a string, it renders as a string as opposed to a partial with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to do this. See below.

```
<%=
  Rails.cache.fetch("trip_owners_#{trip.id.to_s}", expires_in: 7.days) do
    output = ""
    trip.owners.limit(3).each do |owner|

     output += render_user_card(owner)

    end
    output
  end.html_safe
%>
```